# Why isn't the definition of the category of elements of a contravariant functor dual to the definiton of the category of elements of a covariant one?

Tags: category-theory

I'm reading Riehls' Category Theory in Context and came across the following confusion.

Riehl says (page 66):

> For a contravariant functor $F: C^\text{op} \rightarrow \text{Set}$, the category of elements $\int F$ is defined to be the opposite of the category of elements of $F$, regarded as a covariant functor of $C^\text{op}$.

Why do we take the extra op? To me, the dual definition would just be to not distinguish between contra and covariant functors, and just take the normal category of elements of $F$, regarded as a covariant functor of $C^\text{op}$.

Comment: I suspect one wants to have distinct notions of $\int_C F$ and $\int_{C^\mathsf{op}}F$